# Getting issue with VPC in Lambda function

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-vpc, amazon-lambda, amazon-api-gateway

I have attached VPC and private subnets in Lambda function. That is causing the connection issue with the API Gateway/other AWS services. Can anyone suggest the solution for this?

Thank you.

Comment: Hi Gayathri K, if the response below answered your question please upvote and accept it. That's the ServerFault's way to say thank you for the time and effort someone took to help you. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I suspect it’s one of these issues:

- If the *subnet* is “private” it doesn’t have a **NAT gateway** attached, or
- If the subnet is “public” with IGW attached (IGW = Internet Gateway) but doesn’t have **Auto-assign public IP** enabled.
- It could also be a **routing issue** - make sure the *Route Table* for your subnet has a route for `0.0.0.0/0` pointing towards the IGW or NAT gateway.

Hope that helps :)